# same address shows different values for const variable with g++ compiler

Tags: c++, c

The following code shows different output with gcc and g++ on using `const` variable `i`.
The addresses of `i` and value of `ptr` is same, but on accessing that address by printing value of `i` and derefrencing value of `ptr` I got value of `i` as `5` with g++ and `10` with gcc.

How g++ holds const variable in memory?

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
     const  int i =5; 
     int *ptr =(int*)&i;
     *ptr = 10;
     printf("\n %u and %u   and %d  and %d  \n",&i,ptr,i,*ptr);

     return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Not the answer but you should declare `ptr` as a pointer to a const integer. Casting away const is a bad idea!

Comment: Your format string has 5 conversion specs (`%u`/ `%d`) but only 4 arguments follow. Another instance of undefined behavior.

Comment: @undur_gongor And it passes pointers to a "%u" specifier, which is also undefined behavior.

Comment: This code has enough undefined behaviors so they can cancel each other no ? :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are modifying a `const` qualified object. This is not allowed in C ("undefined behavior"). Anything can happen.

Examples:

1. The compiler could put `i` into read-only memory. Writing to `*ptr` would crash your program.
2. It could put it into writable memory and you would just see the 10.
3. It could put it into writable memory but replace all read accesses to `i` by the number 5 (You promised it is `const`, didn't you?).

I guess the C compiler chose 2 while the C++ compiler went for 3.

Comment: Well, within the confines of our physical reality, "anything can happen" is provably untrue. Within the scope of the language, though, sure.

Comment: Yes, but in the context of the question both observed behaviors are fitting to the C standard.

Comment: (+1) Examples are more enlightening than just UB. Some 1, 2, 3 or something else may happen.

Answer (score 5):

Other have commented on the "undefined" nature of what the code is doing. But to explain how this happens is that it is entirely possible that the compiler applied an optimisation and the runtime value of `i` is never passed to the `printf` but instead replaces the `i` with the constant `5`. You did declare it to be `const` so it is not supposed to change.

Comment: (+1) Yes a smart compiler may remove `i` from print statement and replace it with 5.

Answer (score 3):

It may be in memory or it may be hard-coded into your executable. It is `const`; the compiler may perform aggressive optimisations on it.

This is why *you must not modify it*.

Comment: +1, if I recall correctly, it even not consume any modifiable memory (i.e. data memory)

Comment: @Niall: Yep, potentially. The compiler could even bake it directly into your `printf` format string literal argument (though I wouldn't expect it to).

Answer (score 2):

You can dereference/cast `const` as non-cost and overwrite but the behavior is undefined.

As the behaviour is undefined, you may get anything in result, and you should not question why, how etc.

Once the compiler learns your variable is `const`, it is very well allowed to keep this variable in RO memory and/or replace occurances of this variable with the hardcoded value. A C++ compiler may choose not to assign memory to a `const` variable unless you ask its address in your code.

Rule of thumb is, decide whether you want to change a variable or not and make it `const` accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but in this case, the two languages are identical: any attempt to modify a const object is undefined behavior.  In C++ as in C.

Comment: You are right, OP extracts the address of const variable. I rephrased to make it clearer.